# Laravel Nova - How to remove delete button from file field in form

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have set up a form with image upload. By default laravel nova is showing a delete button and choose image button.

According to my requirement, my client wants to keep the image as non-editable (hide delete and choose button) in the laravel nova form.

How can I do this? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bread and butter of Nova micro-customization, either:

1. Make custom field based on default Image field.
2. Use CSS to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to hide "Choose File" button, only possible to hide delete button in some cases.

But for your case you can just hide whole field from edit form.

```
File::make('File')->hideWhenUpdating();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `delete` operation can be disabled from the `field` with following code:

```
File::make('File')->deletable(false);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Turns out it is [documented here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/file-fields.html#pruning-deletion).